# Running Selenium in Docker can't find geckodrvier.exe

Tags: java, docker, selenium

The code works fine locally.

We point at the geckodriver.exe like so
`System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver","src/main/resources/drivers/geckodriver.exe")`

But when we run the service through docker it says it cannot find `src/main/resources/drivers/geckodriver.exe`. Note that it does bring up the service correctly, just fails right when the tests tried to kick off because of the above.

The compiled jar it builds puts it under `BOOT-INF/classes/drivers/geckodriver.exe` but when I tried setting the path to that it didn't work either.

How am I supposed to configure this so that it can keep track of where the geckodriver.exe (and other drivers) are?

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you try Zalenium container - it surprised me how good it works the first time I did.

You can also use their container image as base if you need customizations.

Read more about it at https://opensource.zalando.com/zalenium/

Comment: I will look into this! Always looking for better solutions.